# A blank browser is automatically getting launched when Playwright is executed over Selenium Grid

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, playwright

**Context:**

- Playwright Version: 1.23.0
- Operating System: Windows
- Browser: Chrome/Edge
- Selenium Server: 4.4.0

**Code Snippet**

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        Map<String,String> env = new HashMap<>();
        env.put("DEBUG","pw:browser*");
        env.put("SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL","http://192.168.1.103:4444");

        Playwright playwright = Playwright.create(new Playwright.CreateOptions().setEnv(env));
        Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setChannel("chrome").setHeadless(false));
        Page page = browser.newPage();
        page.navigate("https://playwright.dev/docs/selenium-grid");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // other actions...
        page.context().browser().close();
        playwright.close();
    }
```

**Description of the bug**

I have a Local Selenium 4 Grid setup. Hub and Node both are running on my local system.

**When I am trying to execute the playwright script, it launches 2 browsers instead of 1. And 1 of them is just a blank one.**

I put, DEBUG=pw:browser* for debugging and below is the log.

```
2022-09-17T05:40:12.196Z pw:browser <selenium> connecting to http://192.168.1.103:4444/
2022-09-17T05:40:16.386Z pw:browser <selenium> connected to sessionId=624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550
2022-09-17T05:40:16.386Z pw:browser <selenium> using selenium v4
2022-09-17T05:40:16.387Z pw:browser <selenium> retrieved endpoint ws://192.168.1.103:4444/session/624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550/se/cdp for sessionId=624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550
2022-09-17T05:40:16.392Z pw:browser <ws connecting> ws://192.168.1.103:4444/session/624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550/se/cdp
2022-09-17T05:40:16.442Z pw:browser <ws connected> ws://192.168.1.103:4444/session/624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550/se/cdp
2022-09-17T05:40:23.829Z pw:browser <ws disconnecting> ws://192.168.1.103:4444/session/624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550/se/cdp
2022-09-17T05:40:23.841Z pw:browser <ws disconnected> ws://192.168.1.103:4444/session/624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550/se/cdp code=1005 reason=
2022-09-17T05:40:23.893Z pw:browser <selenium> disconnecting from sessionId=624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550
2022-09-17T05:40:24.638Z pw:browser <selenium> disconnected from sessionId=624ba9e3aa78bdea3f2c987c67574550
```